# Using Chebychev's inequality to prove...

Tags: probability, statistics

The number $C_n$ of disjoint cycles in a uniformly chosen random permutation of $\{1, 2, 3, \ldots , n\}$ has the representation $C_n = \sum_{k=1}^n X_k$ where $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ are independent random variables satisfying $P(X_k = 1) = 1 − P(X_k = 0) = 1/k $.

Use Chebyshev’s inequality to prove that, for any $\varepsilon > 0$,
$P(|(C_n\log(n)) -1| \ge \varepsilon ) \to 0$ as $n → ∞$

I am unsure where even to begin this, however I am aware that the Euler–Mascheroni constant may be of some use here.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Not too sure about this, but a possible direction:  The Chebyshev inequality is a statement about the values of a probability distribution with a certain mean and variance, so it might be useful to determine the probability distribution of Cn (in particular, the mean and variance) given the information about the individual random variables that compose it, and see if that lends itself to getting somewhere.  Maybe, pick some fixed n (like n=3) as a start and see what the distribution of that Cn is etc.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Notice that $$\operatorname E(X_k) = 0\cdot\Pr(X_k=0) + 1 \cdot \Pr(X_k=1) = \frac 1 k. $$ Therefore $$ \operatorname E(C_n) = 1 + \frac 12 + \frac 13 +\frac 14 + \cdots + \frac 1 n. $$

Comment: Interestingly enough, I did some calculations and the $E(C_n)$ that is computed above seems to be approximately equal to $log(n)$, using the natural log.  Can that be a coincidence?  I believe in the original version of the problem, $C_n$ was divided by $log(n)$, which would then make the expectation value approach 1 as n gets large (assuming things converge).  I hope this helps.